# Inject logger when connecting to MongoDB via NestJS

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I'm connecting to MongoDB fine through mongoose and NestJS using the following config:

```
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: configService.get('mongo.host'),
        dbName: configService.get('mongo.dbname'),
        user: configService.get('mongo.username'),
        pass: configService.get('mongo.password'),
        authSource: configService.get('mongo.auth.db'),
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
})
export class MongoModule {}
```

The issue is when an error occurs while connecting to MongoDB the log messages are not formatted properly.  Is there a way to catch connection exceptions and reformat them using our project logging standards?

Comment: I am assuming you are using a custom logger. How did you define it?

Comment: It's an Injectable() logger which extends Logger from @nestjs/common